# App Insights in Django OpencensusMiddleware issue '_is_coroutine'

Tags: django, azure

I am trying to use Azure App Insights for my Django application.

I have followed the tutorial here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python-request

So far, I have only added the middleware and the OPENCENSUS change to my settings.py file in the app.

I installed all necessary dependencies, including the asgiref package that was recommended in a similar post.

I am getting the following error:

```
'OpencensusMiddleware' object has no attribute '_is_coroutine'
```

I don't have anything else to work off and it does not seem like this is a common problem. Has anyone encountered it before or knows more about App Insights than I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue - I downgraded to Django 4.0.8 and that made the error go away...so I would suggest looking at your Django version